# Temporal Join in Hive query (events in close proximity in time)

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a need for a hive query that I'm having difficulty figuring out.

I have a time series that looks like this:

```
time                          source    word1   word2    ...etc
2012-02-01 23:43:16.9988243    0001      2B3B    FAF0
2012-02-01 23:43:16.9993561    0002      2326    ABAA
2012-02-01 23:43:16.9998879    0002      2327    ABAA
```

I need a query such that, if a record in one `source` fulfills specific conditions, in addition to that record, it should also return one or more records *in close proximity in time* from the second `source` fulfilling a different set of conditions.

My attempt so far looks like this:

```
SELECT time
    FROM messages C
    JOIN messages D on
       D.time
           BETWEEN C.time - INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND
           AND     C.time + INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND

    WHERE C.source = '0001'
    AND   D.Source = '0002'
    AND   C.word1 = '2B3B'
    AND   D.word2 = 'ABAA'
```

Which should return the first and second records in the sample data above (It shouldn't return the third, because the time is farther away than .001 seconds).

But the query doesn't work.  The error message is

```
FAILED: SemanticException '0.001' encountered with 0 children
```

Comment: I think your logic is fine, based on your requirement.  You'll need to be careful though, because you are intentionally creating a cross join. Dealing with timestamps in Hive is, in my less than humble opinion, a huge pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a naive solution:

```
select  *

from                    messages c
        cross join      messages m 

where   m.time  between c.time - interval '0.001' second
                and     c.time + interval '0.001' second
                
    and c.word1 = '2B3B'
    and m.word2 = 'ABAA'
    
;
```

---

```
+----------------------------+--------+-------+-------+----------------------------+--------+-------+-------+
|            time            | source | word1 | word2 |            time            | source | word1 | word2 |
+----------------------------+--------+-------+-------+----------------------------+--------+-------+-------+
| 2012-02-01 23:43:16.998824 |   0001 | 2B3B  | FAF0  | 2012-02-01 23:43:16.999356 |   0002 |  2326 | ABAA  |
+----------------------------+--------+-------+-------+----------------------------+--------+-------+-------+
```

---

This is the solution with the good performance

```
select  *

from                    messages c

        join            messages m
        
        on              floor (cast(c.time as decimal(37,7)) / (2 * 0.001))   =
                        floor (cast(m.time as decimal(37,7)) / (2 * 0.001))

where   m.time  between c.time - interval '0.001' second
                and     c.time + interval '0.001' second
                
    and c.word1 = '2B3B'
    and m.word2 = 'ABAA'
    
union all

select  *

from                    messages c

        join            messages m
        
        on              floor ((cast(c.time as decimal(37,7)) + 0.001) / (2 * 0.001))   =
                        floor ((cast(m.time as decimal(37,7)) + 0.001) / (2 * 0.001))

where   floor (cast(c.time as decimal(37,7)) / (2 * 0.001))     <>
        floor (cast(m.time as decimal(37,7)) / (2 * 0.001))
        
    and m.time  between c.time - interval '0.001' second
                and     c.time + interval '0.001' second
                
    and c.word1 = '2B3B'
    and m.word2 = 'ABAA'
```

---

```
+----------------------------+--------+-------+-------+----------------------------+-------+-------+-------+
|            time            | source | word1 | word2 |           _col4            | _col5 | _col6 | _col7 |
+----------------------------+--------+-------+-------+----------------------------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2012-02-01 23:43:16.998824 |   0001 | 2B3B  | FAF0  | 2012-02-01 23:43:16.999356 |  0002 |  2326 | ABAA  |
+----------------------------+--------+-------+-------+----------------------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

#### Illustration

Events A and B are going to be caught by the upper part of the UNION ALL.
Events B and C are going to be caught by the lower part of the UNION ALL.

```
    0        0.002    0.004    0.006    0.008    0.01      
    |        |        |        |        |        |
-------------------------------------------------------
                      |        |
                      |        |
                          A  B  C
                           |        |
                           |        |
-------------------------------------------------------
         |        |        |        |        |                
         0.001    0.003    0.005    0.007    0.009
```

Comment: Thanks.  When you have time, I'd love to see the performant solution.

Comment: So I have a couple of questions about this.  The first question is "is the `between and clause` in the first dataset of the union really necessary?"  It seems as if the `between and` is a superset of the `on` join, as I can remove the `between and` clause and get the same result.

Comment: The second question relates to the first.  If you count the results of each part of the union and add them together, it clearly produces the same result as the naive query, but I don't quite get what the second union dataset represents, or why the first union alone does not correlate exactly to the `between and`, as it seems to me like it should.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - (1) The `between` condition prevents false-positives. (2)  The 2 parts of the UNION ALL represents 2 shifted scales. See updated answer