# How to group together time-related events in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a dataset that looks like this representative dataset (it's a result set from [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240981/temporal-join-in-hive-query-events-in-close-proximity-in-time)):

```
time                          
2012-02-01 23:43:16.9088243 <--
2012-02-01 23:43:16.9093561
2012-02-01 23:43:16.9098879

2012-02-01 23:43:17.1018243 <--
2012-02-01 23:43:17.1023561
2012-02-01 23:43:17.1028879

2012-02-01 23:43:17.2018243 <--
2012-02-01 23:43:17.2023561
2012-02-01 23:43:17.2028879
```

The result contains millions of rows, so now we need a way to thin it out so that we can analyze it.

If you notice, the first three rows of the example above are within one thousandth of a second of each other, but the next three rows are separated by a tenth of  a second, and the following three rows are also separated by a tenth of a second.  I've added blank lines (not in the original data) to illustrate this.

I need a query that will **identify those timestamps that are more than one thousandth of a second away from the previous timestamp.**  The resulting output (assuming the first group of three is also a tenth of a second away from the previous one) would be:

```
2012-02-01 23:43:16.9088243
2012-02-01 23:43:17.1018243
2012-02-01 23:43:17.2018243
```

I've gotten as far as knowing that I probably need some sort of Row_Number functionality and partitioning, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Comment: Millions seems like a non issue even for a localized database.

Comment: Well, you don't necessarily want to  hand someone an Excel spreadsheet with 4 million rows when a few thousand will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(time) over (order by time) as prev_time
      from t
     ) t
where prev_time is null or
      time > prev_time + interval '0.001' second;
```