# Distance between customer location and POI in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, esri

I am trying to compute the distance between each customer and point of interest in hive. But only interested in the point of interest within 30 miles of the customer. The challenge is I have close to 60 MM customer and 2 MM point of interest. The join is expensive one - Is their way to restrict computation by limiting to point of interest within certain radius.

I use the esri package in hive to perform distance computation

Comment: Add a data sample, including requested result.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really an efficient way to reduce the computation of your join without a spatial index of some sort. I'm not aware of any spatial indexing available for the Esri Hive functions (source: I'm a contributor to the project).

Comment: The answer provides accurate information.  If the situation is not as desired, comment on the project's GitHub repo, rather than downvoting a correct answer.

Comment: @RandallWhitman, the "answer" falsely claims "There's not really an efficient way to reduce the computation of your join without a spatial index of some sort", so the "answer" is wrong.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Fair enough. I look forward to your answer.

Comment: @climbage, same concept as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240981/temporal-join-in-hive-query-events-in-close-proximity-in-time/45243037#45243037 but in two dimensions instead of one, which therefore requires four queries instead of two.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Let's hope he only cares about planar distances then.

Comment: @climbage, non planar distance only means that the distance used for tessellation should be changed accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

## Update based on comments:

It appears you need a stepwise approach to take advantage of the optimizations. I have worked the idea out below:

Like in any tool, you can use the 'standard' trick for these kind of problems.

The idea is that you can efficiently know whether things need to be compared because sorting is comparatively cheap. As a result, you can implement something like this:

1. First define categories based on the location (e.g. based on rounding longtitude and latitude on 1 decimal).

After calculating this, your data will look something like this where Entity can be Customer or Poi:

```
Entity: A
lon: 42.0123
lat: 13.3123
lonset: 420
latset: 133
```

Now you can build two strong strong where clauses in your join. The first you can use to create a list of short longtitudinal distance pairs, the second you can use to create a list of short latitudinal distance pairs.

```
Poi.Lonset=Customer.Lonset OR Poi.Lonset=Customer.Lonset+1  OR Poi.Lonset=Customer.Lonset - 1

Poi.Latset=Customer.Latset OR Poi.Latset=Customer.Latset+1  OR Poi.Latset=Customer.Latset - 1
```

Your data should now look like so:

```
Cust: A
Poi: X
londist: 24

Cust A:
Poi: X
latdist: 13
```

Of course this assumes that a lonset and latset is at least 30 miles wide, otherwise you can adjust accordingly.

Now you only need to join these two tables and calculate the distance from them. (As the points are within 30 miles, you can basically use pythagoras for this with good accuracy).

I am not familiar with the Esra package and have not tried to do this in Hive directly, but you can always use Pig, there I can testify that it can do this kind of join in a smart way.

Comment: Does this "very strong where clause" prevents a Cartesian product? What exactly is the Pig's "smart way" for "this kind of join"?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I am not sure how it works under the hood, but based on the performance that I have seen, I think pig splits the data based on the content of your where statement, and only looks at all combinations of customer and poi for which the where clause is matched. So yes, it does prevent a full product.

Comment: Theoretically, a query with this WHERE clause could be rewritten as 9 equijoin queries + a dedup step. I seriously doubt PIG does such a thing. Can you backup your claim with an execution plan?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Can you back up your doubt instead? I no longer have access to the relevant code base, but I have seen the results when I needed to join two large log datasets, which first failed, and then succeeded after I did such a trick to make the where statement look only at records of the same or adjecent hours. -- It may have required a sort (which would make things a bit more complicated for 2 dimensions) but it is definitely possible.

Comment: **(1)** It goes only in one direction :-) It's enough that you'll show a single use-case where it works, but endless use-cases where it doesn't work won't prove that it would never work.  **(2)** There are endless performance myths out there that could be avoided by close examination of the execution plans. Not knowing what was the before and after execution plans leaves us in the myths area.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Still no execution plan, but based on your comment I edited my approach into a stepwise one, so that it should perform as desired.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin how rounding to 1 decimal place ensures points are with in 30 miles? Could you please explain this

Comment: @Naveena It seems I overestimated the distance of 1 decimal place. Based on this [calculator](http://boulter.com/gps/distance/?from=N+42+69.458+W+71+27.826&to=N+42+59.458+W+71+27.826&units=m) you need buckets of size .3 lon/lat to make sure a bucket is at least 30 miles (and thus that you don't 'miss' any hits by just looking at the next bucket). -- If you use buckets of size .1, you could of course make it work by looking at more than just the adjacent ones (=, +-1, +-2)